# What are 'iloc' and 'loc' in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have heard some people saying 'iloc' or 'loc' is a method/function. But in case of a function or method, we always use () brackets.

I want to understand:
If, iloc/loc are functions/methods, then why do we not use () brackets?
Also, if they aren't functions/methods, then what are they and how to understand them?

Also, if you compare them with arrays in c++, then arrays too use integral indexes. So, how come 'loc' uses string for indexes.

Thanks for your answer!

Comment: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/indexing.py#L88

Comment: If you check the docs, [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) is a property, not a method/function. Same for 'loc'.

Answer (score 2):

Both *loc* and *iloc* are **properties**.

In some sense they return something like **array**, so after them
you put index values enclosed just in **brackets**.

The difference between them is that:

- *iloc* provides access to elements (cells) of a *DataFrame*, based on
  their **integer position** (row number / column number), starting from
  *0*,
- *loc* provides access to the same elements (cells), based on **values of
  index** / **column names** of the underlying *DataFrame*.

In case of a *Series* you specify only the integer element number or the
index value (respectively for *iloc* and *loc*).

For further details see the documentation.